# $\varnothing$: Setting Things Straight

Tags: elementary-set-theory

---

> Question: Let $S=\{\varnothing, \{\varnothing\}\}$. Which of the following are/is true?
>
> $\varnothing\subseteq S$
>
> $\varnothing\in S$
>
> $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq S$
>
> $\{\varnothing\}\in S$

---

> OP's Answer: All are true.

---

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LukeMathieson Probably, OP is asking, "My answer is "All of them are true." Is this a correct answer?"

Comment: Since your set $S$ is given by the enumeration of its elements, the questions involving the $\in$ relation can be immediately answered by inspection. Those involving the $\subseteq$ relation, using the definition of $\subseteq$, can be reduced to questions involving only the $\in$ relation, so the same applies to them. With what are you having problems, exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's right. All of them are true.

Note that the first statement is true for any set $S$.

Also, the second and third statement are equivalent.